# Flutter dependencies are deprecated in iOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I know many Flutter developers use lots of different packages in their applications. Nowadays, I'm trying to build a final version of my app in iOS but it gives me headache. I'm using packages such as image_picker, flutter_local_notifications, flutter_inappwebview, firebase_messaging etc. Due to compatibility issue on Firebase libraries, **I need to target min. iOS 10.0.**

These are the versions of some libraries that give errors when building to **iOS on Simulator**.

```
image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1
flutter_inappwebview: ^4.0.0+4

# Only Firebase_messaging gives errors between Firebase libraries but 
# I would like to show you the versions of all of them
firebase_admob: ^0.11.0+1
firebase_messaging:
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
```

A little part of warnings related to firebase_messaging

```
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/zahidtekbas/Documents/GitHub/projectxyz-Flutter-App/projectxyz/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Li
    brary/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:17:32: note: 'UIUserNotificationType' has been
    explicitly marked deprecated here
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
                                   ^
    /Users/zahidtekbas/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin
    .m:294:70: warning: 'UIUserNotificationTypeBadge' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications
    Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        @"badge" : [NSNumber numberWithBool:notificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge],
                                                                         ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/zahidtekbas/Documents/GitHub/projectxyz-Flutter-App/projectxyz/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Li
    brary/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:17:32: note: 'UIUserNotificationType' has been
    explicitly marked deprecated here
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
                                   ^
    /Users/zahidtekbas/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin
    .m:295:70: warning: 'UIUserNotificationTypeAlert' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications
    Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        @"alert" : [NSNumber numberWithBool:notificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert],
```

And there are these kind of deprecated methods, deprecated UI elements errors in warning output. **When I target min. iOS 9.0**, this time GoogleMobilAds, FirebaseInstanceID, flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4 etc. give errors.

So I can't avoid errors and warnings when building for iOS no matter what platform I'm targeting. Any idea how to solve the long paragraphs of error messages due to deprecated stuff?

Edit: I'm adding output of flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.8.pre, on macOS 11.2 20D64 darwin-x64, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-17.8.pre at /Users/zahidtekbas/flutter
    • Framework revision 044f2cf560 (3 days ago), 2021-02-24 13:02:05 -0800
    • Engine revision 042c82b02c
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-259.16.beta)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/zahidtekbas/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 53.0.5
    • Dart plugin version 203.6912

[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.4.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 943E0837-6EB7-45F6-B9F0-EC00160B2CDE • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-3 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.192
```

End of the build output:

```
    4 warnings generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team
    ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Comment: You fix deprecation warnings by changing your code, not your targeted version. Or you ignore them (they're warnings, after all) and deal with the tech debt on your next upgrade.

Comment: @tehhowch It is not about ignoring. I think it prevents me to build the app in iOS. Is there any possibility that suggest otherwise? Do you think it is because of new build system in Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue, even i minimumOSVersion was set to 11.0 , and IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET set to 11.0 , error deprecated still show, maybe ploblem with Xcode , btw i use Xcode 12.4 and 12.2 still error

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to new Flutter version solved my problem. If anyone see this, consider upgrading your dependencies and Flutter.

Comment: I am at flutter 2.5.3 (codemagic) and still getting those "first deprecated in iOS 10.0" warnings.

Comment: @DreamFlasher I am also facing this issue on the latest version of flutter (codemagic). Did you solve it?